# This extension requires the Microsoft ODBC Driver for SQL Server

Tags: php, sql-server

Estou rodando o PHP 8.1.6 no windows server 2012 R2 porém ele aparece esse problema com a requisição:

> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[IMSSP]: This extension requires the Microsoft ODBC Driver for SQL Server to communicate with SQL Server. Access the following URL to download the ODBC Driver for SQL Server for x64: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=163712 in

Já instalei a versão mais recomendada do extensão do sqlsrv e o servidor está reconhecendo normalmente:

[Foto do servidor reconhecendo a extensão](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R4klq.png)

Segue o meu código:

```
try {
    $pdo = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=host;Database=dbname", "user", "pass");
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $sql = $pdo->query("SELECT vp.Vencimento, b.Codigo AS CodBanco, b.Nome, vp.Valor FROM VencPedido vp INNER JOIN Pedidos p ON p.CodPedido = vp.CodPedido INNER JOIN Bancos b ON b.Codigo = CASE WHEN vp.CodBanco IN (0) THEN CASE WHEN p.CodBanco IN (0) THEN 99999 ElSE p.CodBanco END ELSE vp.CodBanco END WHERE vp.CodPedido = $id");

    while ( $row = $sql->fetch( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC ) ){
        array_push($array, $row);
    }
} catch (PDOException $ex) {
    echo $ex;
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Essa imagem mostra que você instalou a extensão do SQL Server para o PDO, mas  , de acordo com a mensagem de erro, você vai precisar de um driver ODBC compatível com a sua versão do SQL Server para poder usar.  https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/connect/odbc/windows/system-requirements-installation-and-driver-files?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: @Bins só faltava isso mesmo, instalei o driver no servidor e deu certo, muito obrigado!